# что делает useCreateIndex в mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

что делает  useCreateIndex в mongo

смотрел  в документации не понял

Comment: Следовало расписать, что именно вы поняли из текста. Подобные односложные вопросы выглядят как нежелание что-либо изучать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, Mongoose 5.x calls the MongoDB driver's ensureIndex()
> function. The MongoDB driver deprecated this function in favor of
> createIndex()

Как видим из [документации](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#createIndex) Mongo:

> `createIndex(fieldOrSpec, options, callback)` creates an index on the db and collection collection.

> `ensureIndex(fieldOrSpec, options, callback)` ensures that an index exists, if it does not it creates it

Короче говоря, опция `{ useCreateIndex: true }` заставляет mongoose использовать `createIndex()` вместо [`ensureIndex()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#ensureIndex), чтобы не было предупреждения о использовании выпиленных из Mongo фич.